# Getting user's email address in Meteor publish function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection Groups with a filed that is an array of user emails. I need to access the email address of the logged in user in a publish function. The following works:

```
Meteor.publish("groups", function() {
  return Groups.find({emails: "hand_coded@email.com"}); 
});
```

Which is quite useless obviously. None of these work:

```
  Meteor.user().emails[0].address
  this.user.emails[0].address
  this.userId.emails[0].address
```

What's the correct way to access the user email address here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you put the `subscribe` function in a reactive context? The publish function may get invoked first when the user is not yet set, in which case `this.user` will be `null`. You should check this in your publish method. Also, according to [the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#publish_userId), there's just `this.userId` parameter available, so you need to fetch the user object yourself:

```
Meteor.publish('groups', function() {
  if(!this.userId) return [];
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
  ... /* use user.emails[0].address to search for and return the right groups */
});
```

Also, wrap your subscribe function in something reactive:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
  Meteor.subscribe('groups');
});
```

Comment: It worked when I fetched the user object -- and thanks for the tip about making the subscribe function reactive as well!